# iPhone iOS how to take a screenshot programmatically with rotation?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uiview, ios6, screenshot

I know how to take a regular rectangular screenshots of the iPhone/iPad screen (code below). However, I'm looking for a way to get a screenshot that is rotated by an arbitrary number of degrees

**How can I take a screenshot of `UIView` using a rectangle that is rotated arbitrarily?**

```
    //this is the rotation of the rectangle
        NSNumber* savedRotation = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 0.35]; //radians, get the real number from a gesture recognizer

        //create a screenshot
        CGSize screenshotSize;

//screenshot size has to be adjusted for the rotation, or multiplied by the square root of 2
        if( UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([[UIApplication sharedApplication]statusBarOrientation]))
        {
            screenshotSize  =  CGSizeMake(1024,768);
        }else
        {
            screenshotSize  =  CGSizeMake(768, 1024);

        }

        if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)])
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(screenshotSize, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);


        else
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(screenshotSize);

        CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        CGContextSaveGState(context);

    //this does the proper rotation, but there's some kind of extra translation required to make it capture what's under the rectangle
        CGContextRotateCTM(context, -savedRotation.floatValue);
        [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];


        UIImage *screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

        CGContextRestoreGState(context);
```

Here's the result of the code above, it seems to partially work, but requires some extra translation of the CTM to perfectly match the capture rectangle. Additionally, I need to change the bounds of the context to be wider ( probably 1024 * sqrt(2) width and height) to allow for any rotation without clipping.

[image]

Comment: You want the frame of the shot to be rotated, so that you have, essentially, a diagonal section of the screen? Or do you want the screen to rotate before you take the shot?

Comment: Actually I have a rectangle overlaid on the screen that defines the screenshot crop area. This rectangle can be rotated by the user. I'm looking to capture whatever is enclosed by the rectangle's frame (which can be at an angle related to the main view)

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code required to crop an image based on a simple rectangle.

I'm not sure how you're tracking your rectangle's rotation, but it should be pretty straight forward from there to apply this solution;

```
// Create rectangle from middle of current image
CGRect croprect = CGRectMake(image.size.width / 4, image.size.height / 4 ,
(image.size.width / 2), (image.size.height / 2));

// Draw new image in current graphics context
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([image CGImage], croprect);

// Create new cropped UIImage
UIImage *croppedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];

CGImageRelease(imageRef);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is pretty much the code I'm using to crop a larger screenshot into smaller ones. Now I need to figure out where/how to do rotation